# Angle formed by summing $n$ unit vectors

Tags: trigonometry, summation, angle

I'm interested in the angle formed by the sum of $n$ unit vectors. Said angle must be a function of the angles of the $n$ unit vectors.

Specifically, suppose that the $i$-th unit vector's angle is $\theta_i$. Then the angle of the sum is

$$f(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n) = \tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{\sin(\theta_1) + \cdots + \sin(\theta_n)}{\cos(\theta_1) + \cdots + \cos(\theta_n)}\Big)$$

which is easy to solve for $n=1,2$

$$f(\theta_1) = \theta_1$$

$$f(\theta_1,\theta_2) = \frac{1}{2}(\theta_1 + \theta_2)$$

Can anyone solve for $n=3$? When

$$f(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) = \tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{\sin(\theta_1) + \sin(\theta_2) + \sin(\theta_3)}{\cos(\theta_1) + \cos(\theta_2) + \cos(\theta_3)}\Big)$$

Here's a graphical representation for $n=3$ (except the vectors are each about 40 units long) where an expression for the angle of the red line is desired.

[image: _]

And can one solve for $n$ in general?

Comment: @Rahul Very interesting. Any elaboration on the $n=3$ case would be greatly appreciated. More specifically, I'm trying to find $a,b,c,d$ that are integral imaginary numbers such that $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = rd^4$. That is to say, $a^4 + b^4 + c^4$ make the same angle with the x-axis as does $d^4$

Comment: I just computed a Taylor expansion using a computer algebra system, there is no more insight than that. // If $a$ is imaginary then $a^4$ is real and positive, so all of your terms make the same angle with the $x$-axis, namely 0.

Comment: $a=m+ni \Rightarrow a^4 = (m^4 - 6m^2n^2 + n^4) + 4mn(m^2-n^2)i$ so unfortunately the angle $a^4$ makes with the x-axis is non-zero when $m \neq n$

Comment: OK, then $a$ isn't imaginary, it's complex. It would be an imaginary number if $m=0$.

Comment: If there was an algebraic function $f \in \mathbb R[\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3]$, then the taylor expansion would be finite. So it is sufficient to prove that the taylor expansion is not finite.

Comment: @flawr The n=2 case has such an expression, but it would seem to also have an infinite number of terms in the taylor expansion. Could you make your claim more specific?

Comment: If a function is a polynomial of degree $d$, then the taylor series truncated at $d$ will result in the polynomial, and all higher order terms are zero.

Comment: @flawr I appreciate the comment, but more explanation is needed since 1) the input of the function in question -- that is, $tan^{-1}$ -- is itself a non-polynomial multivariate function -- specifically $\frac{sin(\theta_1) + sin(\theta_3) + sin(\theta_3)}{cos(\theta_1) cos(\theta_2) + cos(\theta_3)}$. And 2) the n=2 case is solved with a polynomial of degree 1 when the Taylor expansion of $tan^{-1}$ gives a very non-trivial expression. Your idea doesn't account for trig substitutions and other tricks.

Comment: The taylor expansiosn of $\tan^{-1}$ or $\sin$ alone might be infinite each on it's own, but the taylor expansion of the whole function $f$ is finite for $n =1,2$. If you want to understand that a little bit better consider the function $f(x) = \sin^{-1}(sin(x))$. Clearly the taylor expansion is $f(x) = x$, but the series for $\sin^{-1}$ and $\sin$ by themselves are both infinite! If you're not familiar with that I recommend reading up on Taylor polynomials and taylor series. For the case $n=2$ consider the output of the CAS *Maxima* [here](https://tinyurl.com/ya72ocjl) (press "play").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of $n=2$ can simplify thanks to

$$e^{i\alpha}+e^{i\beta}=(e^{i(\alpha-\beta)/2}+e^{-i(\alpha-\beta)/2})e^{i(\alpha+\beta)/2}=2\cos(\alpha-\beta)e^{i(\alpha+\beta)/2}.$$

This simplification does not extend to $n=3$ because the symmetry is broken. In

$$e^{i\alpha}+e^{i\beta}+e^{i\gamma}=2\cos(\alpha-\beta)e^{i(\alpha+\beta)/2}+e^{i\gamma},$$
 the first term has a non-unit coefficient.

I doubt that there is anything better than $$\arg(e^{i\alpha}+e^{i\beta}+e^{i\gamma}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\bf u}_i=(\cos\theta_i,\sin\theta_i)$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$ be the given unit vectors. Then
$${\rm s}:=\sum_{i=1}^n{\bf u}_i=(p,q),\qquad p:=\sum_{i=1}^n\cos\theta_i,\quad q:=\sum_{i=1}^n\sin\theta_i\ .$$
If ${\bf s}\ne{\bf 0}$  we simply have
$${\rm arg}({\bf s})={\rm arg}(p,q)\ .$$
There is not more to it. The essential point is having the function $${\rm arg}:\quad\dot{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}/(2\pi{\mathbb Z})$$ in your mathematical (and computational) toolkit. This function is one of the most important functions of multivariate  analysis. It gives for each point $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ the polar angle of $(x,y)$ modulo $2\pi$. When $x>0$ (and only then) one has
$${\rm arg}(x,y)=\arctan{y\over x}+2k\pi\ .$$
On some pocket calculators this function is accessible as second output of the command ${\tt pol}$ (or similar), and certain outdated programming languages refer to it under ${\tt atan2}$, but with reversed order of the variables. In both cases a single real number is outputted. The waving away of the multivaluedness of ${\rm arg}$ is paid for by a discontinuity along the negative $x$-axis.

Comment: Apologies if this is a naive question but what is "arg" here?

Comment: What is an example of a non-outdated programming language? :)